# How to deal with this AttributeError in scipy? It's very strange

Tags: python, error-handling

This code is just from [SciPy.org](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html#scipy.sparse.save_npz):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(np.array([[0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 0]]))
scipy.sparse.save_npz('/tmp/sparse_matrix.npz', sparse_matrix)
```

But when I run it, it shows: AttributeError: module 'scipy.sparse' has no attribute 'save_npz'

And if I do this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.save_npz
import scipy.sparse

sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(np.array([[0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 0]]))
scipy.sparse.save_npz('/tmp/sparse_matrix.npz', sparse_matrix)
```

It shows: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.save_npz'

And if I do this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, save_npz

sparse_matrix = csc_matrix(np.array([[0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 0]]))
save_npz('/tmp/sparse_matrix.npz', sparse_matrix)
```

It shows: ImportError: cannot import name 'save_npz'

So, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect `scipy.__version__` and you'll see that the version is < 0.19, the first release in which the `save_npz` method is implemented.

You need to run `pip install --upgrade scipy` at a shell prompt.

If you're using iPython or Jupyter, you will need to restart the kernel before the change will take effect.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Where can I find the file(/tmp/sparse_matrix.npz)? I can use 'scipy.sparse.load_npz(file)' to load it. But I cannot find it

Comment: The answer is in your question: it's in `/tmp`. So, `cd /tmp` and you're there. (When you say "find it" do you mean find it in some kind of GUI? If so, which?)

Comment: Yes, I mean find it in some kind of GUI. And my computer is Mac, how can I  find it in GUI?

Comment: Type `open /tmp` in the terminal. Or save it in `~/Documents` instead of `/tmp`.